# MongoDB .Net Driver 2.x - How to execute stored JS function

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, stored-functions

I have a stored JS function in MongoDB as in [Optimistic Loop pattern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#optimistic-loop)
I need to execute it with [MongoDB C#/.NET driver 2.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.0.1) -MongoDb version 3.0.5-.

I can execute it from MongoDB shell like so:

```
myFunc({by:"Bob", on:ISODate("2015-10-02T01:11:18.965Z")}, db.myCollection)
```

`db.Eval` has been [deprecated since 3.x](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/):
I thought maybe `db.runCommand()` might do what I want. But cannot figure out how to actually represent a function call with `JsonCommand`/`ObjectCommand`/`BsonDocumentCommand`
[`RunCommand(String)`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_RunCommand_1.htm) seem to have been deprecated as well.

So how do I run stored function from C#/.NET client?

**Edit 1**:
I could have implemented the pattern in C#, but don't want the overhead of reading before writing, surely it will be faster if run on MongoDB server.

**Edit 2**:
So far I understood that statement in my Edit 1 is wrong, because running functions from `mongo.exe` client will make same amount of calls if I implement pattern in C#, therefore there is no benefit implementing auto incrementing counters using JS functions.

Comment: If you are running like that from the "shell" then it is not actually running on the "server" but on the "client" ( that is what [`db.loadServerScripts()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.loadServerScripts/#db.loadServerScripts) does), the only way things run on the server are within an "eval" or within a JavaScript processor like mapReduce or possibly `$where`. Both have limitations and "warnings" attached. Just about anything you concieve you "need" serverside JavaScript in the fashion for is better implemented in the native methods provided.

Comment: @BlakesSeven, yes I run stuff from shell, do I understand you correctly that if I was to implement Optimistic Loop pattern in C# (double journey for read & write) then I will not gain speed (by saving journey count) as same would happen from shell? Thanks!

Comment: What you need to "correctly" understand is that there are inherrent problems with executing server side code in the JavaScript engine, in the manner of any "flow control" operations you believe you are writing. You only "think" you need it because of your current design and approach to the problem you really have. What you really "should" do is reconsider the design required, and possibly ask questions about the problems you want to solve that drove you to your design in the first place. It's likely if you do, others will suggest better ways. Things get "deprecated" for good reasons.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Let me destil the requirement: I need an auto incremented id. Independent of the persistence technology, there is nothing inherently wrong with design involving such pattern. Agree?

Official MongoDb tutorial suggests doing it with server-side JS. You say it is wrong per se. Fine. How one should implement such a common pattern then?

Comment: Which tutorial? I know of no such thing. What I think you are referring to does **not** use server side JavaScript at all, but rather setting sequence counters in a table using `.findAndModify()`. As for independent, well storing JavaScript would require an engine to do that, so it doesn't sound very independant. If you can do a "totally" indepdant storage logic, then good luck. Such implementations have a way of ignoring the better features by trying to be generic. Anyhow your question in this form self answers. Call "eval". If you want better alternatives, then ask people as I suggest.

Comment: No, I'm not making a generic storage logic. What I'm trying to say is that I have a requirement for id's of my objects to be sequentially incremented. So no matter what the implementation details / persistence mechanism chosen are, requirement must be fulfilled. So i'm trying to find the best way to do it in MongoDb. From what you say I understand that: if I was to implement pattern in C#, then it would be the same (in the amount of calls caried out) as it described in this tutorial: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#optimistic-loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
var cmd = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{ eval: \"myFunc({by:\"Bob\", on:ISODate(\"2015-10-02T01:11:18.965Z\")}, db.myCollection)\" }");
var result = db.RunCommand(cmd);
```